# Can we pass dictionary as argument to python script; I am trying to pass mydict argument with value as "mydict = {"name": "test"}

Tags: python

```
import pymongo
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
# establish connectivity to Mongodb via ssl using pymongo module
args = sys.argv

host = sys.argv[1]
mydict = sys.argv[2**strong text**]
#print (args)
port = "27017"
print(uname)
print(passwrd)
uri = 'mongodb://' + uname + ":" + passwrd + "@" + host + ":" + port + '/?authSource=admin'

client = MongoClient(uri, ssl=True, ssl_ca_certs='./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')
# This will create feedtst docdb
print("connected client")
mydb = client.feedtst  # This command will create a DB 
print(client.list_database_names()) # This command will print list of DBs
print(client.list_database_names()) # This command will print list of DBs
mycol = mydb[ "feed1234"]  # This command will create a collection in DB
docins=mycol.insert_one(mydict)  # This will insert a document in collection
dblist = client.list_database_names()
print(client.list_database_names())
```

For above python script **I am trying to pass mydict argument with value as "mydict = {"name": "test"}";**  B**ut its giving error ypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument**

Comment: pass dict as json object,  ** import  json,   docins=mycol.insert_one(json.dump(mydict)) **

Comment: python pymongo-dict-arg.py 'docdb-test.cluster-czzpyhxnqlzh.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com' '{"name":"tstng","name":"tstng2"}'; ** It giving error as dump() takes atleast 2 arguments

Comment: Sorry,  its **json.dumps(mydict)**

Comment: Tried that as well, its giving error; Instead of json.dumps() I used json.loads() its working fine.

Comment: Ok, i am posting the answer, it will be useful for others

Comment: It isn’t clear to me what your question is, and we don’t appear to have a [mcve].